# H >= timeofday work H = timeofday not work

Tags: google-sheets

1. =QUERY('Лист1'!A1:W3780; "SELECT H, O, W WHERE H >= timeofday '10:30:00' AND W > 0")
   In this forms >= formula worked but i need form 2
2. =QUERY('Лист1'!A1:W3780; "SELECT H, O, W WHERE H = timeofday '10:30:00' AND W > 0")

please help me understand 1) work  2) did not work

thanks

1. =QUERY('Лист1'!A1:W3780; "SELECT H, O, W WHERE H >= timeofday '10:30:00' AND W > 0")
   In this forms >= formula worked but i need form 2
2. =QUERY('Лист1'!A1:W3780; "SELECT H, O, W WHERE H = timeofday '10:30:00' AND W > 0")

please help me understand 1) work  2) did not work

thanks

Comment: How many instances of this EXACT timing `10:30:00` were in Column H (do a manual check) and whats the output and error code(if any) given out by the query?!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.